# How to perform a date range elasticsearch query given multiple dates per document?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm using ElasticSearch to index forum threads and reply posts. Each post has a date field associated with it. I'd like to perform a query that includes a date range which will return threads that contain posts matching a date range. I've looked at using a nested mapping but the docs say the feature is experimental and may lead to inaccurate results.

What's the best way to accomplish this? I'm using the Java API.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You haven't said much about your data structure, but I'm inferring from your question that you have `post` objects which contain a `date` field, and presumably a `thread_id` field, ie some way of identifying which thread a post belongs to?

Do you also have a `thread` object, or is your `thread_id` sufficient?

Either way, your stated goal is to return a list of threads which have posts in a particular date range. This means that you need to group your threads (rather than returning the same `thread_id` multiple times for each post in the date range).

This grouping can be done by using [facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/search/facets).

So the query in JSON would look like this:

```
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:9200/posts/post/_search?pretty=1&search_type=count'  -d '
{
   "facets" : {
      "thread_id" : {
         "terms" : {
            "size" : 20,
            "field" : "thread_id"
         }
      }
   },
   "query" : {
      "filtered" : {
         "query" : {
            "text" : {
               "content" : "any keywords to match"
            }
         },
         "filter" : {
            "numeric_range" : {
               "date" : {
                  "lt" : "2011-02-01",
                  "gte" : "2011-01-01"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
'
```

Note:

- I'm using `search_type=count` because I don't actually want the posts returned, just the `thread_id`s
- I've specified that I want the 20 most frequently encountered `thread_id`s (`size: 20`). The default would be 10
- I'm using a `numeric_range` for the `date` field because dates typically have many distinct values, and the `numeric_range` filter uses a different approach to the `range` filter, making it perform better in this situation
- If your `thread_id`s look like `how-to-perform-a-date-range-elasticsearch-query` then you can use these values directly. But if you have a separate `thread` object, then you can use the [multi-get](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-get.html) API to retrieve these
- your `thread_id` field should be mapped as `{ "index": "not_analyzed" }` so that the whole value is treated as a single term, rather than being analyzed into separate terms

Comment: First, thanks for the lengthy and informative answer. 

My final solution was a little different. I basically created an array of "postDates" of type Date for each thread document. From there, I do a range query. I may look into changing to a numeric_range filter for the performance as you suggested.

Thanks again!

Comment: You shoud use histogram facet if you want data versus time

Comment: @ThomasDecaux I think you should reread the question. And no, my date format is not wrong: http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/ISODateTimeFormat.html#dateOptionalTimeParser%28%29

Comment: Just a note, I think this answer is out of date now - "Facets are deprecated and will be removed in a future release. You are encouraged to migrate to aggregations instead."